# How to enable authentication in mongo db multiple databases for existing users

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I have mongo version 3.2.5 installed in my windows production machine and want to secure it
and put authentication.
There is a total of three DBS 1. admin, 2. Appdb and 3. local.
below is users in both DB and for local no user, it seems.

```
> use admin
switched to DB admin
> show users
{
        "_id" : "admin.root",
        "user" : "root",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "root",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ]
}

> use appdb
switched to db appdb
> show users
{
        "_id" : "appdb.appuser",
        "user" : "appuser",
        "db" : "appdb",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "dbAdmin",
                        "db" : "appdb"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "appdb"
                }
        ]
}
```

now please guide me how to secure them.

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: What is your question? What do you mean by "how to secure them"?

Comment: MongoDB version 3.2.5 is more than 5 years old - how did you actually get the package? You should install a more recent version.

Comment: I want to Enable authentication or restrict access to the MongoDB service.

Comment: Just restart the database with `--auth` option, resp. add `security.authorization: enabled` in the [configuration file](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-security.authorization) Maybe have a look at [Enable Access Control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/)